# Version conflict error while installing albumentation on python 3.6.8 with opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, pip, python-3.6, albumentations

I'm trying to install `albumentations` on python 3.6.8. However, the installation is failing with the following error

```
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, 
which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This is happening because my Python version is 3.6.8 and the installed opencv-python version is 3.4.13.47 and albumentation is trying to install the latest version of opencv-python (4.7.x). As per the install instructions of albumentations as given [here](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/installation/), there is a flag to force-use the existing opencv version

```
pip install -U albumentations --no-binary qudida, albumentations
```

However, even after using these flags, albumentation is trying to install  opencv-python-4.7.0.72, and this is failing.

How can we force this to use the existing opencv version?

Comment: Albumentations requires python 3.7 atleast. Take a look here https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations/blob/master/setup.py#L67.

Comment: something is broken if your system doesn't want to use the *binary packages of opencv-python*. a python version that's long out of support would be a very good reason for that. opencv 3.4 is also quite dead. you'd better switch to 4.x